# How to avoid hiding logs in logCat?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I have a problem with my Eclipse. LogCat just holds messages about 10 seconds and after that they will disappear before i can read them.

Anyone knows how to **avoid** hiding logCat messages?

Edit:I don't know what's going wrong with my LogCat. When i connect my galaxy s2 device it shows around 1000 messages in just 2 or 3 seconds!

here is one of them.they are mostly like this:

```
01-24 16:56:47.353: D/(2001): [HYPOS] NOMOVE Time 24653125, PowerMode 2, GPSWeakSignal 54, GPSFixTime 0, IsPedestrian 0, DOE 3editcode here
```

Comment: Try going to Window -> Preferences -> LogCat -> Maximum number of logcat messages to buffer, have a look if that's limiting it (mine is 5000)

Comment: Isn't the Scroll Lock button at the top right of the LogCat window enough to prevent messages from disappearing?

Comment: Thanks NKN, mine is 5000 to.when i connect the real device LogCat immediately shows thousand of messages and they got to be removed.I filtered my app name there is less messages but they got disappear to :-(

Comment: @Piovezan: no it does not solve anything

Comment: What you're experiencing seems to be a bug, see more info here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=797895 You should be able to get rid of this putting a filter, though. Did you set it correctly?

Comment: Yes I did.but the filtered messages are member of all messages and they will be delete after exceeding Maximum number of logcat messages to buffer

Answer (score 1):

LogCat view got limit on number of lines it keeps in scroll buffer. By default it is set to 5000 lines. On some devices, where activity is high, this can be not sufficient. To increase the limit go to Ecplise settings: `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `LogCat` and increase value of `Maximum number of logcat messages`.

Note that freezing autoscroll is NOT a solution. You just freeze the autoscroll but data are still being read from the device and placed in logcat buffer.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. but would you read the edit.The real problem is there

Comment: I do not see any problem there. It's just one of many things that are being send to logcat. If you want to understand every line displayed, then I do not think it is a task you can acommplish easily

Comment: No it is not normal.I don't want to understand the messages, I wonder why they are being sent at such a high rate (1000 message in just 2 seconds! and nonstopable).anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the use of the following command in command prompt which will provide you all logs,

> > adb logcat > LogFileName.txt

Again you can customize this based on your device or emulator names when more than one devices or emulators are available by specifying their names.